# Display the users that have not yet created projects this month in specific city (count=0)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to list my clients that haven't created yet a project in a specific city.

```
SELECT u.userName
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT userName FROM projects) u
LEFT JOIN projects p
    ON u.userName = p.userName AND
       MONTH(p.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
       YEAR(p.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
       p.city = "Bordeaux";
WHERE
    p.userName IS NULL
```

This code list all my clients with no project but the city filter don't work.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

EDIT : Live exemple : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53de526/5

Comment: You seem to have a spurious `;` after `"Bordeaux"`

Comment: p.city = "Bordeaux";    
why you have semicolon there, is there any specific reason for that

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and note that a range query will likely prove more efficacious

Answer (score 2):

Your `LEFT JOIN` query will return a `NULL` `userName` value for rows which don't match *any* of the `JOIN` conditions so it will return a lot of results that are not what you want. A `NOT EXISTS` subquery would work better in this scenario:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userName
FROM projects p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM projects p2
                  WHERE p2.userName = p1.userName
                    AND MONTH(p.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
                    AND YEAR(p.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
                    AND p.city = "Bordeaux")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use aggregation:

```
SELECT p.userName
FROM projects p
GROUP BY u.userName
HAVING SUM( MONTH(p.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
            YEAR(p.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
            p.city = 'Bordeaux'
          );
```

If you have a separate list of users, then I would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from projects p
                  where p.username = u.username and
                        month(p.date) = month(CURRENT_DATE()) and
                        year(p.date) = year(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
                        p.city = 'Bordeaux'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to include p.city = 'Bordeaux' in your WHERE query. Not your ON clause.